# JavaFX: Proyecto pizzeria, problema con ingredientes

Tags: java, javafx

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de práctica para mi asignatura de programación en Java y he encontrado un problema que no alcanzo a ver.

El programa simula una pizzería. Se puede elegir el tamaño, tipo de masa, ingredientes, etc... de la pizza y el programa va recalculando el precio a medida que se cambian opciones. Llegado el momento, si pulsas sobre "Añadir al pedido", la aplicacion guarda la pizza en una lsita de pizzas y te va mostrando el resumen del pedido. Finalmente se pulsará sobre "Generar ticket" y se generará un archivo txt con el resumen del pedido (ahora mismo el ticket esta hecho para la version anterior, en la que no se guardaban las pizzas, sino que se elegian las opciones y directamente se imprimia el ticket).

El problema que tengo es que cuando guardo la primera pizza, todo parece estar bien, pero cuando guardo la seguna pizza, tanto la primera como la segunda pasan a tener los ingredientes aidicionales de la segunda. Esto afecta al resumen del pedido, al precio, etc...Por otro lado, esto parece no ocurrir cuando la primera o la segunda pizza no tienen ingredientes adicionales.

Esta es las clase "Pizza"

```
package modelo;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Pizza {
    String masa;
    String tipo;
    String tamanyo;
    Boolean bebida;
    Boolean gratinada;
    ArrayList ingredientes = new ArrayList();
    Precios precio = new Precios();
    Double precioMasa = 0d;
    Double precioTipo = 0d;
    Double precioTamanyo = 0d;
    Double precioIngredientes = 0d;
    Double precioBebida = 0d;
    Double precioGratinada = 0d;

    public Pizza(String masa, String tipo, String tamanyo, Boolean bebida, Boolean gratinada) {
        this.masa = masa;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.tamanyo = tamanyo;
        this.bebida = bebida;
        this.gratinada = gratinada;
    }

    public Pizza(){}

    public String getMasa() {
        return masa;
    }

    public void setMasa(String masa) {
        this.masa = masa;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public String getTamanyo() {
        return tamanyo;
    }

    public void setTamanyo(String tamanyo) {
        this.tamanyo = tamanyo;
    }

    public ArrayList getIngredientes() {
        return ingredientes;
    }

    public void setIngredientes(ArrayList ingredientes) {
        this.ingredientes = ingredientes;
    }

    public void setBebida(Boolean bebida){
        this.bebida = bebida;
    }

    public Boolean getBebida(){
        return bebida;
    }

    public Boolean getGratinada(){
        return gratinada;
    }

    public void setGratinada(Boolean gratinada){
        this.gratinada = gratinada;
    }

    public Precios getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(Precios precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public Double calcularPrecio(){
        Double precioPizza;
        precioIngredientes = 0d;
        precioTipo = precio.getPrecioTipo(tipo);
        precioMasa = precio.getPrecioMasa(masa);
        for(int i = 0; i < ingredientes.size(); i++){
            precioIngredientes += precio.getPrecioIngredientes(ingredientes.get(i).toString());
        }
        precioTamanyo = precio.getPrecioTamanyo(tamanyo);
        precioBebida = precio.getPrecioBebida(bebida);
        precioGratinada = precio.getPrecioGratinada(gratinada);
        precioPizza = (precioMasa + precioTipo + precioIngredientes) * precioTamanyo;
        precioPizza *= precioGratinada;
        precioPizza += precioBebida;
        return precioPizza;
    }

    public ArrayList composicion(String addStr){
        ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<>();
        String ingr = "";
        String strTamanyo = "";
        String strBebida;
        String strGratinada;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        Double incrPrecioTamanyo = (precioTamanyo * 100d) - 100d;
        Double incrPrecioGratinada = (precioGratinada * 100d) - 100d;
        String strPorcentajeTamanyo = String.valueOf(df.format(incrPrecioTamanyo));
        String strPorcentajeGratinada = String.valueOf(df.format(incrPrecioGratinada));
        for (int i = 0; i < this.ingredientes.size(); i++){
            if(i < this.ingredientes.size() - 1){
                ingr += this.ingredientes.get(i).toString() + ", ";
            }else{
                ingr += this.ingredientes.get(i).toString();
            }
        }
        if(this.bebida){
            strBebida = "Sí - " + precioBebida;
        }else{
            strBebida = "No - 0";
        }
        if(this.gratinada){
            strGratinada = "Sí - " + strPorcentajeGratinada;
        }else{
            strGratinada = "No - 0";
        }
        strTamanyo = String.valueOf(incrPrecioTamanyo);

        str.add("MASA: " + this.masa + " - " + precioMasa + "€"); 
        str.add("TIPO: " + this.tipo + " - " + precioTipo + "€");
        str.add("INGREDIENTES: " + ingr + " - " + precioIngredientes + "€");
        str.add("TAMAÑO: " + this.tamanyo + " - " + strPorcentajeTamanyo + "%");
        str.add("GRATINADA: " + strGratinada + "%");
        str.add("BEBIDA: " + strBebida + "€");
        str.add(addStr);

        return str;
    }
}
```

...Y este es el FXMLDocumentController, donde intuyo que está el problema, aunque a estas alturas, ya, ni idea...

```
package pizzeria_1.pkg0;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory.ListSpinnerValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import modelo.Pizza;
import modelo.Precios;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    private final ArrayList listaIngredientes = new ArrayList();
    private final ArrayList listaTipos = new ArrayList();
    private final ArrayList listaTamanyos = new ArrayList();
    private final ArrayList listaMasas = new ArrayList();
    private final ArrayList opciones = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList<Pizza> pizzas = new ArrayList();
    private String eleccionTipo;
    private final ArrayList eleccionIngr = new ArrayList();
    private String eleccionTama;
    private Boolean eleccionBebida;
    private Boolean eleccionGratinada;
    private double precioFinal = 0d;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    private final ObservableList<String> listaObservableIngredientes = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private final ObservableList<String> listaObservableTipos = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private final ObservableList<String> listaObservableTamanyos = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Pequeña", "Mediana", "Familiar");

    private Pizza miPizza = new Pizza();

    @FXML
    private Button calcular;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton masa_normal;
    @FXML
    private ToggleGroup tg_masa;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton masa_integral;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> tipo;
    @FXML
    private ListView<String> ingredientes;
    @FXML
    private Spinner<String> tamanyo;
    //private TextArea pedido;
    private Label precio;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox bebida;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox gratinada;
    @FXML
    private Button generarTicket;
    @FXML
    private Button addPizza;
    @FXML
    private TextArea resumenPizza;
    @FXML
    private Label precioPedido;
    @FXML
    private Label precioPizza;
    @FXML
    private TextArea resumenPedido;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        listaIngredientes.add("jamon");
        listaIngredientes.add("queso");
        listaIngredientes.add("tomate");
        listaIngredientes.add("cebolla");
        listaIngredientes.add("olivas");

        listaTipos.add("Básica");
        listaTipos.add("Cuatro Quesos");
        listaTipos.add("Barbacoa");
        listaTipos.add("Mexicana");

        listaTamanyos.add("Pequeña");
        listaTamanyos.add("Mediana");
        listaTamanyos.add("Familiar");

        listaMasas.add("Normal");
        listaMasas.add("Integral");

        listaObservableIngredientes.addAll(listaIngredientes);
        ingredientes.setItems(listaObservableIngredientes);
        ingredientes.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        listaObservableTipos.addAll(listaTipos);
        tipo.setItems(listaObservableTipos);

        ListSpinnerValueFactory<String> tamanyos = new SpinnerValueFactory.ListSpinnerValueFactory(listaObservableTamanyos);
        tamanyo.setValueFactory(tamanyos);
        calcular.setVisible(false);
        calcularPizza();

    }    
    @FXML
    public void calcularPizza(){
        clearPizza();
        eligeMasa();
        eligeTipo();
        eligeIngredientes();
        eligeTamanyo();
        eligeBebida();
        eligeGratinada();

        escribirPrecioPizza();
        escribirPizza();

    }

    public void escribirPizza(){
        ArrayList<String> comp = miPizza.composicion("");
        String out = "";
        for(int j = 0; j< comp.size(); j++){
            out += comp.get(j) + "\n";
        }

        resumenPizza.appendText(out);
    }

    public void clearPizza(){
        resumenPizza.setText("");
        eleccionIngr.clear();

    }

    public void calcularPrecioPedido(){
        for(int i = 0; i < pizzas.size(); i++){
            precioFinal += pizzas.get(i).calcularPrecio();
        }
        precioPedido.setText(String.valueOf(precioFinal));
    }

    public void escribirPedido(){
        ArrayList<String> comp = new ArrayList<>();
        String out = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < pizzas.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(pizzas.get(i).getIngredientes());
            System.out.println("-");
            out += "Pizza #" + String.valueOf(i+1) + "\n";
            comp = pizzas.get(i).composicion("");
            for(int j = 0; j< comp.size(); j++){
                out += comp.get(j) + "\n";
            }
        }
        resumenPedido.appendText(out);
    }

    public void clearPedido(){
        resumenPedido.setText("");
        ingredientes.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        bebida.setSelected(false);
        gratinada.setSelected(false);
        masa_normal.setSelected(true);
        masa_integral.setSelected(false);
        tamanyo.getValueFactory().setValue("Pequeña");
        tipo.setValue("Básica");
        precioFinal = 0;
    }
        @FXML
    private void addPizza(ActionEvent event) {
        pizzas.add(miPizza);        //Añado la pizza actual al arraylist
        miPizza = new Pizza();      //creo una nueva pizza
        calcularPrecioPedido();     //calculo el precio total de las pizzas del arraylist
        clearPedido();              //limpio el texto del pedido
        escribirPedido();           //y ahora lo escribo con las pizzas del arraylist
        clearPizza();               //pongo los campos del formulario por defecto
        calcularPizza();            //calculo la seleccion actual


    }

    @FXML
    private void generarTicket(ActionEvent event) {
        String str = "";
        ArrayList<String> comp = miPizza.composicion("");

        String precioTotal = String.valueOf(miPizza.calcularPrecio());

        Date fecha = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yy_hh-mm-ss");
        String fechaStr = df.format(fecha);
        String nombreArchivo = "src/tickets/Ticket-" + fechaStr + ".txt";
        //String nombreArchivo = "src/tickets/archivo.txt";
        Path archivo = Paths.get(nombreArchivo);
        try(BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(archivo, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.CREATE)){
            for(int i = 0; i< comp.size(); i++){
                bw.write(comp.get(i));
                bw.newLine();
            }
            bw.write("Precio Total: " + precioTotal + "€");
        }catch(IOException e){
            miPizza.composicion("\n\nError al crear el ticket.");
        }
    }

    public void escribirPrecioPizza(){
        precioPizza.setText(String.valueOf(miPizza.calcularPrecio())+"€");
    }

    public void eligeMasa() {
        if(masa_normal.isSelected()){
            miPizza.setMasa("Normal");
        }else if(masa_integral.isSelected()){
            miPizza.setMasa("Integral");
        }else{
            miPizza.setMasa("Normal");
            masa_normal.setSelected(true);
        }
    }

    public void eligeTipo(){
        eleccionTipo = tipo.getValue();
        if(eleccionTipo != null){
            miPizza.setTipo(eleccionTipo);
        }else{
            miPizza.setTipo("Básica");
            tipo.getSelectionModel().select("Básica");
        }
    }

    public void eligeIngredientes(){
        eleccionIngr.clear();
        for (String str : ingredientes.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()) {
            if(str != null){
                eleccionIngr.add(str);
            }
        }
        if(eleccionIngr.size() > 0){
            miPizza.setIngredientes(eleccionIngr);
        }
    }

    public void eligeTamanyo(){
        eleccionTama = tamanyo.getValue();
        if(eleccionTama != null){
            miPizza.setTamanyo(eleccionTama);
        }
    }

    public void eligeGratinada(){
        eleccionGratinada = gratinada.selectedProperty().getValue();
        miPizza.setGratinada(eleccionGratinada);
    }

    public void eligeBebida(){
        eleccionBebida = bebida.selectedProperty().getValue();
        miPizza.setBebida(eleccionBebida);
    }
}
```

Para no copiar aqui el resto de código, dejo un [enlace al proyecto entero](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OS2pAknqNOg1Hy08E_khrAKw7_IblKwE), por si ayuda en algo.

Edito: Por si sirve de algo, aqui muestro como elijo una primera pizza con extra de "Jamón" y al añador al pedido una segunda pizza con Extra de "Cebolla", ahora las dos parecen tener extra de "Cebolla" y ni rastro del "Jamón":

[image: Ejemplo de uso de la aplicación]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al pasar como parámetro una colección a otro bjeto (como en el cao de los ingredientes), se pasa la dirección de memoria, y no los datos en sí. La solución pasa por volver a crear una colección nueva para los nuevos elementos, de una de las siguientes maneras:

```
ingredientes = new HashSet<>();
setIngredientes() //De la clase Pizza, crear un nuevo ArrayList con los datos
                  //del parámetro y asignarlos al atributo ingredientes de la pizza
```

La respuesta es de mi profesora, no quisiera atribuirme un mérito que no me corresponde, pero en cualquier caso, problema resuelto y ojalá que pueda ayudar a otros en algún momento.

A @Jorgesys, muchas gracias por el interés!

Comment: Podrías pasar de nuevo el proyecto entero? Me interesaría ver cómo has realizado el proyecto, porque tengo uno muy similar. Me harías un gran favor, mil gracias!!!

Comment: Lo buscaré y te lo paso, faltaría más!

Answer (score 0):

El problema por el cual se muestran los ingredientes extras al agregar una nueva pizza se debe a que en el metodo `addPizza()` debes crear una nueva instancia de `Pizza` antes de agregarla a el array `pizzas`, de esta forma

```
@FXML
private void addPizza(ActionEvent event) {

    miPizza = new Pizza();      //creo una nueva pizza
    pizzas.add(miPizza);        //Añado la pizza actual al arraylist

    calcularPrecioPedido();     //calculo el precio total de las pizzas del arraylist
    clearPedido();              //limpio el texto del pedido
    escribirPedido();           //y ahora lo escribo con las pizzas del arraylist
    clearPizza();               //pongo los campos del formulario por defecto
    calcularPizza();            //calculo la seleccion actual


}
```

Comment: Buenos dias! La pizza "inicial" ya estaba creada al principio de la clase. En esas líneas que me comentas, primero añado la pizza que ya tenía creada al array "Pizzas" y a continuación creo una nueva. Por eso está en ese orden. Aún así, he probado a hacerlo como tú me dices, pero me devuelve un error, imagino que porque simplemente estoy machacando la pizza que ya tenía creada con todos sus datos por una vacía, y al tratar de calcular el precio, devuelve el error.

Comment: Al llegar a este punto pizzas ya contiene la que tenias creada, pero estas agregando como una nueva la que ya existe "pizzas.add(miPizza);" la cual contiene las propiedades y después estas creando otra  miPizza = new Pizza();

Comment: Nada me gustaría más que estar equivocado en este caso, y puede que sea así, pero no consigo ver en qué momento agrego miPizza al pedido (pizzas.add(miPizza)). Solo veo que tengo una pizza (miPizza) creada al momento de inciar la aplicacion, y que solo cuando le doy al boton de agregar al pedido la guarda en el arraylist. Entonces, y solo entonces, creo una nueva pizza con el mismo nombre que la anterior (miPizza = new Pizza();). Al guardarla en el arraylist, lo hago con ".add), por lo que en teoría la esta guardando a la derecha de la primera, no? Sea como sea, gracias por estar ayudandome!